# How to get rid of KDE's overlay of app icons in cursor when opening a file

Tags: taskbar, kde-4, cursor, kde-plasma-workspace

Whenever I open a file in KDE (Suse 12.3) the corresponding app's icon is shown next to cursor and the name appears with spinning wheel in taskbar. Normally this disappears very soon and is OK. However if the app is already open (say file editor) and I open a file the spinning in taskbar & cursor overlay(with jump effect to boot) continues for a while & then disappears.

This is incredibly distracting & annoying. Any way to disable this?